# Flask Uploading Image and Text At the Same Time

Tags: flask

So what I am trying to achieve here is to upload and image and text at the same time. So far it has worked, but on Flask, the `request.files` is empty. However, `request.form` returns me this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('description', u''), ('name', u''), ('file', u'image.jpg')])
```

When I do `type(request.form['file'])` it returns as unicode. How do I make it such that I can have the image on `request.files` and the text on `request.form`

```html
<form class="form-area " id="" action="{{ url_for('templater.test') }}" method="post"  novalidate>
       
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text">

  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <input name="description" placeholder="Enter Description" type="text">

  
  <input type = "file" name = "file" />

  <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

```
@templater.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    print request.form
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'file' not in request.form:
            print 'No file part'
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.form['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(main.app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

    return jsonify({'status':'something'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the `enctype` attribute in the form tag :

```
<form class="form-area " id="" action="{{ url_for('templater.test') }}" method="post"  novalidate  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

By adding that, you should be able to call the files

```
 files = request.files.getlist('file')
 for file in files:
     [...]
```

And the other inputs are still available in the form:

```
request.form.get('name')
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)